# Подсчитать количество книг у автора

Tags: c

Нужно для каждого автора подсчитать количество книг. Результат выдать в виде таблицы из двух колонок: ФИО автора и количество книг. Содержимое таблицы должно быть упорядочено по убыванию количества книг. Язык C. Есть библиотека, содержащая какое-то количество книг, представленных структурой:

```
struct book 
{ 
char author[NAME_SIZE]; //автор 
char name[NAME_SIZE]; //название 
char publish[NAME_SIZE]; //издательство 
int year; //год выпуска 
int pages; //количество страниц 
char genre[NAME_SIZE]; //жанр 
};
```

Библиотека располагается в отдельном текстовом файле.

Я примерно представляю как подсчитать кол-во, но не понимаю как это вывести, чтобы соответствовало требованию?

Comment: Ну и в чем именно проблема у вас?

Comment: Я примерно представляю как подсчитать кол-во, но не понимаю как это вывести, чтобы соответствовало требованию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заводишь структуру под результат:

```
struct books_count
{
  char author[NAME_SIZE]; 
  unsigned count;
}
```

Заполняешь массив таких структур (можно сделать оптимальнее, но пойдёт и так), сортируешь его как требуется, вычисляешь самое длинное имя автора (оно используется для выравнивания таблицы - формирует ширину поля для вывода имени автора):

```
unsigned len;
```

Считаем что на количество книг хватит 5 символов и каждую строку выводим вот так:

```
printf("%*s %5u\n", -len, res[q].author, res[q].count);
```

Comment: @Kromster, В условии нет. Она используется, как понимаю, для выравнивания таблицы - формирует ширину поля для вывода имени автора